# Transpose 3D coordinates on a plane to a new 2D coordinate system

Tags: python, image-processing, graphics, geometry, linear-algebra

I have been working on a personal project to produce an image of the integer solutions to the equation x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = S where 'S' is any integer.

In other words, I am looking for all the 3D points [x,y,z] where x, y, and z are all perfect square integers and x + y + z = S

For example, S = 2809 will have solutions:

- [144, 1296, 1369],
- [144, 729, 1936],
- [0, 0, 2809]
- ... plus all permutations of the above (i.e. 144+729+1936 = 1936+729+144)

Before I get to my question, here is a small tangent for some context:

All of the solutions to the general equation x + y + z = S will lie on a 2D plane defined by:

- A = [S, 0, 0]
- B = [0, S, 0]
- C = [0, 0, S]

Here is a graph of all solutions (not just square points) to x + y + z = 50 to illustrate that all of the solutions to this equation will lie on the same plane bounded by ABC defined above. Notice that the tips of the triangle below are: [50, 0, 0], [0, 50, 0], and [0, 0, 50]

[image: ABC plane]

Back to my question:
After finding the square solution points, I want to transpose the 3D solution points into 2D coordinates based on the ABC plane with A as (0,0), B is the max 'x' value, and C is the max 'y' value. I then hope to output these solutions to an image file.

My linear algebra knowledge is sparse, and I have been unable to find a method to transpose 3D coordinates into 2D plane coordinates based on 3 non-colinear points.

My code is currently in python, but an algorithmic/mathematical answer is just as good!

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: this question has at least 3 distinct questions I can see. Please focus your question to the form of "my input is" and "desired output" so that we can help you better

Comment: @Gulzar Not sure which other questions you're seeing. Input: Set of 3D points. Desired output: set of 2D points on the ABC plane with A as the origin.

Comment: I think you're using the term "transpose" when you mean "transform" (or maybe project) — transpose means basically "swap". Also, any 3 distinct points define a plane, so saying "non-colinear points" is meaningless.

Comment: @martineau, P1=(1,2,3), P2=(2,4,6), P3=(3,6,9) are three distinct points which do not define a plane, but rather a line, as P2 and P3 are both linear combinations of P1. Thus the 'non-colinear' part is not meaningless

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I see it, you can already find your `(x, y, z)` points, and your question is about a way to project them onto a plane.

Please refer to [projection matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camera_matrix) to learn how to project the 3d world onto an image plane of your choosing.

Specifically, you will have to express your `(x, y, z)` coordinates as [homogeneous coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates) by refering to them as `(x, y, z, 1)`, and to multiply them by a relevant camera matrix which is orthogonal to the plane on which you need to cast them.

This will yield 2d homogeneous coordinates of the form `(x', y', f)` from which you will be able to obtain the projected coordinates by `(x_projected, y_projected) = (x'/f, y'/f)`.

[OpenCV](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d0/daf/group__projection.html) is your friend.

**Recap:**

1. Input: `n` `(x, y, z)` points
2. Obtain projection (camera) matrix `M` of size `(4, 3)` using opencv or calculate yourself using whatever tools.
3. Add last dimension `1` to all points to get them as 3d homogeneous coordinates: `n` points `(x, y, z, 1)`
4. Multiply all points by the matrix to obtain projected points as 2d homogeneous coordinates: `M * (x, y, z, 1)^T` = `(x', y', f)`
5. Get `n` actual 2d  projected coordinates (relative to camera center as defined by the `M` matrix) by `(x, y)` = `(x'/f, y'/f)`

Bonus: you can stack all your `(x, y, z, 1)` points as columns into a `(4, n)` matrix, `P`, and the entire multiplication process will be `R = M * P`, a result matrix `R` of shape `(3, n)` whose columns are the resulting homogeneous coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

I think Gulzar's answer is correct, but more centered around rendering (i.e. camera and homogenous coordinates). I did however figure out how to do what I wanted.

```
import ast
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def dot_3d(a, b):
    return (a[0]*b[0])+ (a[1]*b[1]) + (a[2]*b[2])

def minus_3d(a, b):
    return [a[0] - b[0], a[1] - b[1], a[2] - b[2]]

def midpoint_3d(a, b):
    return [(a[0] + b[0])/2, (a[1] + b[1])/2, (a[2] + b[2])/2]

def normalize_3d(vec):
    magnitude = math.sqrt(vec[0]**2 + vec[1]**2 + vec[2]**2)
    return [vec[0]/magnitude, vec[1]/magnitude, vec[2]/magnitude]

X = 2809

A = [X, 0, 0]
B = [0, X, 0]
C = [0, 0, X]

S = set([])
for a in range(X+1):
    if int(math.sqrt(a))**2 == a:
        for b in range(X+1):
            if int(math.sqrt(b))**2 == b:
                for c in range(X+1):
                    if int(math.sqrt(c))**2 == c and a + b + c == X:
                        S.add(str([a, b, c]))
S = list(S)

origin = A
normal = normalize_3d([X/3, X/3, X/3])
ax1 = normalize_3d(minus_3d(B, A))
ax2 = normalize_3d(minus_3d(C, midpoint_3d(A, B)))

answers = []

for point_str in S:
    point = ast.literal_eval(point_str)
    x = dot_3d(ax1, minus_3d(point, origin))
    y = dot_3d(ax2, minus_3d(point, origin))
    answers.append([x, y])

plt.scatter([p[0] for p in answers], [p[1] for p in answers])
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.show()
```

Starting 3D coordinates graphed:
[image]

"projected" coordinates on the ABC plane:
[image]

Comment: care to explain geometrically what you did?

Comment: Also, notice the functions `dot_3d`, `minus_3d`, `midpoint_3d` can be expressed using the (standard) numpy library with `a * b`, `a - b`, and `(a + b) / 2` correspondingly, given two `np.array`s. Also, `normalize_3d` can be done using `normalized_v = v / np.sqrt(np.sum(v**2))`.
I don't quite understand the projection part from your code

Comment: Even better, `normalized_v = v / np.sqrt(np.sum(v**2))` can be `normalized_v = v / np.linalg.norm(v)`