# Python - Translate vertices to a different axis

Tags: python

I am struggling with the following. I have 2 surfaces with the following vertices:

```
# Triangle
[[ 50.  50. 100.]
 [100.   0.   0.]
 [100. 100.   0.]]

#Square
[[  0. 100.   0.]
 [  0. 100. 100.]
 [100. 100.   0.]
 [100. 100. 100.]]
```

Now here is how they look in a 3D chart:
[image]

And:
[image]

Now I want to apply some kind of translation on both these vertices so that both surfaces lay flat on the XY axis. I got this working for both figures, but the problem is that I need a function which can handle any given surface to be translated. I can provide code of what I had, but I don't think that that will help, because the code I have is written specifically for a triangle and square.

Working with these vertices is kinda new for me, so I don't know a lot of tricks, but I would really appreciate some tips on how I can  achieve this!

My default code:

```
import trimesh
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

vertices = np.array([[0, 100, 0], [0, 100, 100], [100, 100, 0], [100, 100, 100]])

fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
    ax.scatter(vertices[:, 0], vertices[:, 1], vertices[:, 2])
    plt.show()
```

### UPDATE

After the given answer, I build an implementation of [this](https://github.com/Funderburger/mpi-planar-correction/blob/7f028b052d5fecc14dcb1502306e9ac65942a31f/MonoDepth-FPN-PyTorch/main_fpn_curv_grad.py#L325) method. Mine looks like this (not sure if it does work):

```
def find_plane(pts, thresh=0.05):
    """
    Find the equation of a plane from a set of points that lie on the plane.
    :param pts: 3D point cloud as a `numpy.array (N,3)`.
    :param thresh: Threshold distance from the plane which is considered inlier.
    :returns:
    - `plane_eq`:  Parameters of the plane using Ax+By+Cy+D `torch.tensor (1, 4)`
    """
    n_points = pts.shape[0]

    # We have to find the plane equation described by three points on the plane
    # Select three random points
    pt_samples = pts[:3]

    # We find first 2 vectors that are part of this plane
    # A = pt2 - pt1
    # B = pt3 - pt1
    vecA = pt_samples[1, :] - pt_samples[0, :]
    vecB = pt_samples[2, :] - pt_samples[0, :]

    # Now we compute the cross product of vecA and vecB to get vecC which is normal to the plane
    vecC = np.cross(vecA, vecB)

    # The plane equation will be vecC[0]*x + vecC[1]*y + vecC[0]*z = -k
    # We have to use a point to find k
    vecC = vecC / np.linalg.norm(vecC)
    k = -np.sum(np.multiply(vecC, pt_samples[1, :]))
    plane_eq = [vecC[0], vecC[1], vecC[2], k]

    # Distance from a point to a plane
    # https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-PlaneDistance.html
    pt_id_inliers = []  # list of inliers ids
    dist_pt = (
        plane_eq[0] * pts[:, 0] + plane_eq[1] * pts[:, 1] + plane_eq[2] * pts[:, 2] + plane_eq[3]
    ) / np.sqrt(plane_eq[0] ** 2 + plane_eq[1] ** 2 + plane_eq[2] ** 2)

    # Select indexes where distance is biggers than the threshold
    pt_id_inliers = np.where(np.abs(dist_pt) <= thresh)[0]

    return torch.tensor(plane_eq), pt_id_inliers
```

But I am running into a problem. After calling this method I need to apply it on my vertices, so I tried this:

```
# Plot the points
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')


plane_eq, inliers = find_plane(vertices)

# Extract the inlier points from the original vertices
inlier_points = vertices[inliers]

# Find the centroid of the inlier points
centroid = np.mean(inlier_points, axis=0)

# Compute the normal vector of the plane using the plane equation
normal = plane_eq[:3]

# Compute the distance of the plane from the origin
distance = plane_eq[3] / np.linalg.norm(normal)

# Compute the projection of each point in the inliers onto the plane
projected_points = inlier_points - np.outer(np.dot(inlier_points - centroid, normal), normal)

# Construct the new set of vertices by adding the projected points to the plane
transformed_vertices = np.concatenate((projected_points, np.array([centroid + distance * normal])))
ax.scatter(transformed_vertices[:, 0], transformed_vertices[:, 1], transformed_vertices[:, 2], c='green', marker='o')

plt.show()
```

The error I am getting is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[289], line 167
    165 print(distance)
    166 print(normal)
--> 167 transformed_vertices = np.concatenate((projected_points, np.array([centroid + distance * normal])))
    168 print(transformed_vertices)
    169 ax.scatter(transformed_vertices[:, 0], transformed_vertices[:, 1], transformed_vertices[:, 2], c='green', marker='o')

TypeError: Concatenation operation is not implemented for NumPy arrays, use np.concatenate() instead. Please do not rely on this error; it may not be given on all Python implementations.
```

These are the values I am trying to concatenate:

```
centroid: [83.33333333 50.         33.33333333]
distance: tensor(-89.4427, dtype=torch.float64)
normal:   tensor([0.8944, 0.0000, 0.4472], dtype=torch.float64)
```

Again, I am not sure if I am doing this correctly, so all the help is welcome!

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might help you (as it seems a bit similar, even though I can't really figure out that code without trying it): [Transpose 3D coordinates on a plane to a new 2D coordinate system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63983534/transpose-3d-coordinates-on-a-plane-to-a-new-2d-coordinate-system)

**BUT**, if the short answer is not working/helping there might be another solution, though. If I understand correctly, you are trying to bring 2D shapes found on different planes onto the same common plane.

For that you will have to translate and rotate your points like it is explained here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1167717/transform-a-plane-to-the-xy-plane. Now you only need the equation of the plane to which your 2D shape belongs.

Fortunately for you, I found a code which does exactly that (even though it's a bit messy):

1. Here is [the line](https://github.com/Funderburger/mpi-planar-correction/blob/master/MonoDepth-FPN-PyTorch/main_fpn_curv_grad.py#L166) that computes the plane coefficients, a pytorch [RANSAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_sample_consensus) implementation. (note that there is a [similar method](https://github.com/Funderburger/mpi-planar-correction/blob/master/MonoDepth-FPN-PyTorch/main_fpn_curv_grad.py#L270-L323) which does the same thing in numpy)
2. You'll have to modify the input arguments, such that `minPoints=3`, `maxIteration=1` as you don't need to find a plane that fits your points (which is what RANSAC does), as all the points are already on the same plane.
3. [This code](https://github.com/Funderburger/mpi-planar-correction/blob/master/MonoDepth-FPN-PyTorch/main_fpn_curv_grad.py#L205-L229) will do, basically, the exact mathematical operations as in the above stackexchange link (as the last line will give you the projected points on the xy plane, no matter the orientation of your initial plane).

Hope it helps & happy projection!

**EDIT**
Here is a version (that seems to be working) of the projection with some of the code you provided and the projection specified in the stackexchange thread:

```
import trimesh
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

def find_plane(pts, thresh=0.05):
    """
    Find the equation of a plane from a set of points that lie on the plane.
    :param pts: 3D point cloud as a `numpy.array (N,3)`.
    :param thresh: Threshold distance from the plane which is considered inlier.
    :returns:
    - `plane_eq`:  Parameters of the plane using Ax+By+Cy+D `torch.tensor (1, 4)`
    """
    n_points = pts.shape[0]

    # We have to find the plane equation described by three points on the plane
    # Select three random points
    pt_samples = pts[:3]

    # We find first 2 vectors that are part of this plane
    # A = pt2 - pt1
    # B = pt3 - pt1
    vecA = pt_samples[1, :] - pt_samples[0, :]
    vecB = pt_samples[2, :] - pt_samples[0, :]

    # Now we compute the cross product of vecA and vecB to get vecC which is normal to the plane
    vecC = np.cross(vecA, vecB)

    # The plane equation will be vecC[0]*x + vecC[1]*y + vecC[0]*z = -k
    # We have to use a point to find k
    vecC = vecC / np.linalg.norm(vecC)
    k = -np.sum(np.multiply(vecC, pt_samples[1, :]))
    plane_eq = [vecC[0], vecC[1], vecC[2], k]

    # Distance from a point to a plane
    # https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-PlaneDistance.html
    pt_id_inliers = []  # list of inliers ids
    dist_pt = (
        plane_eq[0] * pts[:, 0] + plane_eq[1] * pts[:, 1] + plane_eq[2] * pts[:, 2] + plane_eq[3]
    ) / np.sqrt(plane_eq[0] ** 2 + plane_eq[1] ** 2 + plane_eq[2] ** 2)

    # Select indexes where distance is biggers than the threshold
    pt_id_inliers = np.where(np.abs(dist_pt) <= thresh)[0]

    return plane_eq, pt_id_inliers

if __name__ == "__main__":
    vertices = np.array([[0, 100, 0], [0, 100, 100], [100, 100, 0], [100, 100, 100]])

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
    ax.scatter(vertices[:, 0], vertices[:, 1], vertices[:, 2])
    
    plane_eq, inliers = find_plane(vertices)

    # Extract the inlier points from the original vertices
    inlier_points = vertices[inliers]
    
    # compute the projection matrix
    a = plane_eq[0]
    b = plane_eq[1]
    c = plane_eq[2]
    d = plane_eq[3]

    cos_theta = c / math.sqrt(a**2 + b**2 + c**2)
    sin_theta = math.sqrt((a**2+b**2)/(a**2 + b**2 + c**2))
    u_1 = b / math.sqrt(a**2 + b**2 )
    u_2 = -a / math.sqrt(a**2 + b**2)
    pred_rotation_matrix = np.array([[cos_theta + u_1**2 * (1-cos_theta), u_1*u_2*(1-cos_theta), u_2*sin_theta],
                            [u_1*u_2*(1-cos_theta), cos_theta + u_2**2*(1- cos_theta), -u_1*sin_theta],
                            [-u_2*sin_theta, u_1*sin_theta, cos_theta]])

    pred_rotation_matrix = np.transpose(pred_rotation_matrix)
    transposed_points = np.matmul(inlier_points,pred_rotation_matrix)

    ax.scatter(transposed_points[:,0],transposed_points[:,1],transposed_points[:,2],c='red',marker='*')

    plt.show()
```

**LATER EDIT**
For your specific code I just saw that there are simpler ways to compute the equation of a plane, based on three points (if the points of your geometric shapes are always all on the same plane):

```
def equation_plane(vertices):
    x1, y1, z1 = vertices[0][0],vertices[0][1], vertices[0][2]
    x2, y2, z2 = vertices[1][0],vertices[1][1], vertices[1][2]
    x3, y3, z3 = vertices[2][0],vertices[2][1], vertices[2][2]
    
    a1 = x2 - x1
    b1 = y2 - y1
    c1 = z2 - z1
    a2 = x3 - x1
    b2 = y3 - y1
    c2 = z3 - z1
    a = b1 * c2 - b2 * c1
    b = a2 * c1 - a1 * c2
    c = a1 * b2 - b1 * a2
    d = (- a * x1 - b * y1 - c * z1)
    return [a, b, c, d]
```

Comment: Based on your answer, I added an update section to my question with more code and errors ofcourse :)

Comment: Well, I can see a few problems there. First, you can remove the `torch.tensor()` in the return statement of the `find_plane` function. Also, for the `np.concatenate` to work, change  `normal = plane_eq[:3]` to `normal = np.array(plane_eq[:3])`. But even so, I tested this and it does not seem to work as the `transposed_vertices` are the same as the original `vertices` + another point (the centroid). Either way, I updated my response with a working version of the projection. Hope it helps! :D

Comment: Also, I just found that it didn't work  in the case of the triangle and I fixed that, as the projection matrix was not correctly transposed.  Now it should work just fine! :) If you have more questions, let me know.

Comment: Yes thank you for your help, this does exactly what I want it to do, so marked answer as accepted. Still one thing that I interested to know. I have to check your code on what everything does exactly, but is it easy to apply the reverse on those `transposed_points`?

Comment: Glad I could help and to be honest, I don't even understand myself the mathematical part where the projection matrix (`pred_rotation_matrix` awful name in this case, sorry!)  is calculated, but the important part is the projection matrix, so if you want your points to come back to their original state, all you need to do is to multiply the transposed points with the transposed projection matrix, e.g. `rev_transposed_points = np.matmul(transposed_points,np.transpose(pred_rotation_matrix))`.

Comment: Love to you man! thanks for your help